# Advice on how I should return more than a simple type from my service layer

Tags: wcf

In my mvc3 application, I have things setup like:

```
1. repositories for each entity
2. service class for each entity that wraps the bare nhibernate db calls with business logic
```

Now for example, a class that registers a user, I want the service class to return something more than a boolean or user object if the user can register successfully.

Is this good practise?

Reason being, a person may fail to register correctly for reasons like:

```
1. duplicate email address in the system
2. duplicate username
3. etc.
```

So my method may look like:

```
public User Register(User newUser)
{
   // check for a user with the same email
   // check for a user with the same username

   // validation checks etc.

   return user;
}
```

I am thinking of creating a UserRegistrationResponse object so I can return back a much richer return value.

So something like:

```
public UserRegistrationResponse Register(User user)
{
  ..

  return userRegistrationResponse;
}
```

This way I can return back a user frienly response I can propogate to the UI layer, and still get the user object and other information etc.

**Comments on this approach?**

*I guess the only other way would be to throw exceptions, but is that really a good idea?*  The idea is for me to able to re-use these service classes, like say in a Restful service layer I will need in the future.

Comment: Is there anything that has led you to think there is something wrong with the approach you mention? It looks fine to me. Exceptions should only be thrown in exceptional circumstances: incorrect password entries are not exceptional.

Comment: Someone once mentioned to me this was like c or c++ style, so I'm confused now really :)

Comment: Looks good to me. You have created a type which represents what happens when a user registers.  This can now hold all the state related to that action.

Comment: I've done something similar, but return a class (OpResult<T>) that contains a boolean for success, and some other goodies like Errors related to validation and so on. <T> is an enum for the specific operation, so that you can the switch on that in the UI layer as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very common.  10 out of 10 WCF projects I've worked on in the past 3 years used this pattern.  This includes legacy projects at three different companies, green field development and mvc/webforms projects.